# Set x and y label in one line

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

If I want to set the x, y label for each axis, I have to do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('This is y label')
plt.xlabel('This is x label')
plt.show()
```

I need to set `xlabel`, `ylabel` seperately.

I'm wondering if there is any syntax sugur that I can do something like:

```
plt.label('x label', 'y label')
```

so the code looks more compact?

Or how can I make any custom function to do this?

Comment: Does your code (or do you) really suffer from writing these two lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you start using the object oriented model of matplotlib more often, you'll be able to add all relevant parameters of an axes as keywords to the functions that make these axes.

A simple example:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, xlabel="time", ylabel="money")
```

A longer example:

```
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax1 = fig1.add_axes((0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8), # full positional control
    frameon=True,                         # display frame boundary
    aspect='equal',                       # set aspect ratio upon creation
    adjustable='box',                     # what part of the axes can change to meet the aspect ratio requirement?
    xticks=[0.1, 1.2, 10],                
    xlabel='voltage (V)',
    xlim=(0.05, 10.05),
    yticks=[0, 10],
    ylabel='current (µA)',
    ylim=(0, 2))
```

Following up on the received comment, you can also make use of the "property batch setter" `ax.set`, which is a nice little matplotlib convenience function.

```
plt.close('all')
plt.plot([1,2,3], [4, 7, 1])
plt.gca().set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y')
```

Comment: Could you provide an example with modifying the `ax`'s label value, besides initiating a new one?

Comment: Thanks alot. An additional thought, could you give me a link of the documentation? I also want to combine it with `legend` setting.

Comment: @cqcn1991 the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=set#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set) can be read online (and in an interactive python shell). This particular docstring is quite short, simply because it is a convenience function that can change all *properties* of an axes. You'll need some familiarity with the `axes` to know which are the properties you can change, but those are a lot of things.

Comment: Seems like I can only do `plt.gca().legend(loc='best')` ?

Comment: @cqcn1991 we're drifting away from your initial question here, but indeed, a legend is not a parameter you can pass this way (check out this [list of valid `kwargs`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes)). It's a method and should be called as such.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def grap_label(g, lx='',ly=''):
    plt.xlabel(lx)
    plt.ylabel(ly)
    plt.show()

grap_label(plt.plot([1,2,3,4]), 'This is x label','This is y label')
```

Comment: Yes, I'm making a very similar function, except that I set `lx = None` as default value. But I think settiing it to empty string is more clever. So I don't have to make an if statement to check if it is `None`

Comment: It is not a good idea to write function which use `plt`, you should write functions that take in axes objects and then work on them.